# urlopen only working for certain URLs in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

So I'm trying to get the URL of a page in python3...

If I do the following,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://google.com/")
html.read()
```

I get the html as desired. 
However, if I were to choose a different url, as in the following,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
html.read()
```

I get the following error after the **second** line:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
File      "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 461, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 574, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 499, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Any ideas why this would be happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closer at the error message you'll see that it is a HTTP error and a special one:

```
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

So you talked to the server and got your response back but you don't know why you were denied.

You can get a more detailed message in an HTML returned by the server with something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

try:
    html = urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.read().decode('utf-8'))

html.read()
```

For me it says:

```
<h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
<p>The owner of this website (www.stackoverflow.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (213702c58d2116a6-ua48).</p>
```

You can treat `HTTPError` as a file object (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError):

> Though being an exception (a subclass of URLError), an HTTPError can
>   also function as a non-exceptional file-like return value (the same
>   thing that urlopen() returns). This is useful when handling exotic
>   HTTP errors, such as requests for authentication.